# Convert pointer to iterator in STL set / delete element in std::set using pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, iterator, set

I have a set which stores a lot (upwards of 50k) of double type values on the heap:

```
struct user {
  int id;
  double score;
}

set <user*, user_comparator_descending_score> USERS = new set ...
```

I also create a

```
map<key, list of pointers to elements in the aforementioned set>
```

that is

```
map<id, vector<user*> > = new map...
```

Now I would like to erase the elements pointed to by the key in this map. I would use the `set::erase` function but it only accepts the iterators pointing to the element to be erased. Would I be correct to use `delete(pointer)` to remove the object from the set? I am quite uncertain of this because set does not use contiguous memory.

Other solutions to my problem would also be highly appreciated. I keep the set sorted in descending order of the values. I require insertion and deletion in `O(logN)`. However, note that deletion is not by value in the set but by some other key.

Comment: Show the definition of the set.

Comment: Not clear what you are looking for but maybe you are looking for `set::erase(*pointer)`?

Comment: Just have your map store set iterators, rather than pointers. You can easily get from iterator to the pointer should you need one (as in, `&*iter`), but you can't go the other way.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Would the iterator still point to the same element after several insertions and consequently, several adjustments in the underlying Red-Black Tree?

Comment: Yes it would. Set iterators are not invalidated when inserting and erasing elements (except, of course, when the element the iterator points to is being erased).

Comment: @KerrekSB I included roughly the structures of the set, hope it helps. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @Named Could you perhaps link me to the definition of that method. I can't find it on [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/erase/)

Comment: Thanks @IgorTandetnik. It works for me. Another equivalent and perhaps cleaner solution is to use a multi-index multimap like the Boost::Bimap. However it has obvious space overhead as far as I have looked into it.